# Why Axes' Ticks depending on Position in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I am defining position as constant (101) in Code 1, while as a decimal number (1.01) in Code 2. 
I am considering the difference between the codes in axes' ticks. 
Code 1

```
hFig=figure('Visible', 'on', 'Units', 'inches', 'Position', [0 0 15 15]); 
set(gca, 'position', [0 0 101 101]);
xlabel(gca, 'Time/s');
x = 0:0.01:1;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
```

Output without axes' ticks

[image]

Code 2

```
hFig=figure('Visible', 'on', 'Units', 'inches', 'Position', [0 0 15 15]);     
set(gca, 'position', [0 0 1.01 1.01]);
xlabel(gca, 'Time/s');
x = 0:0.01:1;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
```

Output with axes' ticks

[image]

---

In both cases, there is no output of `xlabel` for some reason. 
This may be related to the axes' ticks -problem. 
Changing the position of the command did not change the behaviour. 
There are axes' ticks in code 2's output but not in code 1's output.

---

Why is there such a different between outputs in axes' ticks?

Comment: Do you understand what `position` does?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  You mean the second position, for instance: `[left bottom width height]`. So 0 left, 0 bottom, but A width and A height. Here, I assume I can give any value for width and height. So why not decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues here.

1. You keep referencing `gca` without explicitly creating an `axes`. As a result, your `xlabel` is getting applied to the wrong thing because `gca` is *actually* referring to an `axes` in some other figure. To fix this, try something like.

   ```
   fig = figure();
   axes('Parent', fig)   % Explicitly create the axes
   xlabel(gca, 'xlabel')
   ```
2. The `Position` property of the `axes` (by default) is *normalized units*. This means that all of the values are between 0 and 1. As you can see in your second example, you have the last two elements of the position array (width and height) set to 1.01 which is greater than 1 and makes you plot *bigger* than your figure. In your first example, you have set the width and height to 101 which is **way** higher than 1 and causes the size of the axes to be 100 times bigger than your figure. If you look carefully you can even see that your axes is so big in the first case that it looks like a different curve. Also, this is why you don't see any axes ticks.
3. The `Position` is the position of the axes itself and *does not* include the xticks, yticks, xlabels, ylabels, or title. Since you are effectively making your axes as big as your figure you will not see any of these labels as you have it. If you want to set the axes position and automatically take into account the space needed for the tick labels etc., you will want to set the `OuterPosition` property instead.

   ```
   set(gca, 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1])`
   ```

Comment: @Masi You *figure* is 15x15 *inches* your `axes` uses normalized units because you *did not* specify anything else explicitly. You can easily check this with `get(gca, 'Units')`. Also I'm not sure what you mean by the second sentence. It sounds like it worked for you?

Comment: @Masi You do realize that a `figure` is not the same as an `axes` right? `gcf` refers to the current figure and `gca` refers to the current `axes`

Comment: @Masi MATLAB will gladly do whatever you tell it to do with regards to the position. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question. the properties of the `axes` and `figure` are never linked and never will be for good reason (you can have multiple `axes` within a single `figure`)

Comment: @Masi I have no idea what that means

Comment: I mean common understanding about how position of axes relative to figure.

Comment: @Masi You can use either Normalized (default) or absolute positioning. Normalized positioning is relative to the parent (typically a figure).